# vue v-for: translate with switch in vue i18n

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a problem to translate the information with vue i18n that is called through "v-for", all the data from the template is translated without problem, but those that I export through arrays and scripts do not render

i am using vue-i18n: version 7.8.1

Comment: Could you please show what you see and explain what you expect to see? Also, what version of vue-i18n are you using?

Comment: hi Phil, add images and vue-i18n version to the question i hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only ever setting the `helpTitles` property when your component is created.

I would suggest using `$t()` in your templates instead of within `data()`. Then it will automatically react to changes.

I honestly don't think using an array from the translation file is a great idea. I'd be more inclined to add them with their own keys, just like your question and info translation keys, eg

```js
helpStartedTitle: "GETTING STARTED - MODEL",
helpMembersTitle: "MEMBERS",
helpAccountTitle: "ACCOUNT",
//etc
```

You could then set up the keys in your data like this

```js
data: () => {
  const keys = [
    "helpStarted",
    "helpMembers",
    "helpAccount", 
    "helpPayment", 
    "helpSocial", 
    "helpFraud", 
    "helpSupport",
    "helpStudio"
  ]

  return {
    helpInfo: keys.map((key, id) => ({
      id,
      title: `general.help.${key}Title`,
      question: `general.help.${key}`,
      answer: `general.help.${key}Info`
    }))
  }
}
```

then in your template

```html
<div v-for="help in helpInfo" :key="help.id">
  <div :id="help.id" class="help-subtitle">{{ $t(help.title) }}:</div>
  <HelpItem
    :question="$t(help.question)"
    :answer="$t(help.answer)"
    :num="help.id"
  />
</div>
```

---

Even better would be to just pass the translation keys through to your `HelpItem` component and use `$t()` with it.

```html
<HelpItem
  :question="help.question"
  :answer="help.answer"
  :num="help.id"
/>
```

and in the `HelpItem` component

```js
export default {
  name: "HelpItem",
  props: {
    question: String,
    answer: String,
    num: Number
  },
  // etc
}
```

```html
<!-- just guessing here -->
<h1>{{ $t(question) }}</h1>
<p>{{ $t(answer) }}</p>
```

---

FYI, I've corrected `answear` to `answer` throughout.

Comment: True, thank you very much, the part that I was trying to translate works perfectly, but when I change the code in the template, the questions and information are not shown, the keys are correct, it may be a small programming error, really thank you very much

Comment: I checked yesterday but I still have a problem to send the strings to the component, I tried the two ways you show me, but they are not displayed in the app, sorry im new in vuejs.